# BlocklyやScratchをゲーム内で操作する方法

Tags: unity3d, mit-scratch

現在このようなゲームを作っています。
https://fromalgorithm.jimdo.com

今後，このゲームを元にプログラミング教育系で利用されるようなゲームをUnityで作る予定です。
その中で BlocklyやScratchをゲーム内で操作して遊ぶゲームを作りたいのですが，どのようにすればいいのかわかりません。

検索しても，UnityのエディタとしてScratchを使う方法ばかりです。
今のところ詰んでいる状態なので何か前に進める情報などあれば教えてください。

Blockly
https://developers.google.com/blockly/

Scratch
https://scratch.mit.edu

Answer (score -1):

Unityが外部のJSと連携できるなら、Blockly1.0を比較的簡単に呼び出せるんじゃないかな。http://www.catch.jp/wiki/index.php?Blockly%2FCustomBlock